# how to create RandomAccessFile from InputStream?

Tags: java, java-io

The only way I know is to write a temp file, and read this file to create RandomAccessFile ,check it [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/277378/Streams/java/InputStream-RandomAccessFile-best-way)

or use Use Unified I/O library (http://uio.imagero.com) [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t140932-create-randomaccessfile-from-inputstream.html)

Would this be the best way? Or can use temp file and the  imageio library to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for random access of an InputStream you must buffer the stream (at least up to the point requested).  A library like Unified I/O should work, or you can implement DataInput and DataOutput, which will have your class operating like a RandomAccessFile except for the file part if you have custom buffering needs.